# Initialize float variable in the extreme values

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

Hi I want to initialize an device variable in the biggest float number and so far I am doing it like this:

```
float *max;
checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&max, 1));
checkCudaErrors(cudaMemset(max, std::numeric_limits<float>::max(), 1));
```

of respectively to the minimum float number

```
float *min;
checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&min, 1));
checkCudaErrors(cudaMemset(min, std::numeric_limits<float>::min(), 1));
```

This done using `#include <limits>`. Is there any other alternative way without making any includes? For example, I have seen in this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/296az74e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)e that `uchar`  has maximum value `0xff`. Is there any corresponding acronym for the min and max of a float?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that [`numeric_limits<float>::min`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/min) is not the smallest possible `float`. You want [`::lowest`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/lowest).

Comment: You can hard-code values like `0xff` if you don't care about portability. Your life will be much easier if you use the tools that the language provides. Why do you want to avoid `#include`s?

Comment: Not a specific reason. Just wanted to know how it is possible without any include.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not correct. `cudaMemset` sets *bytes*, just like `memset`.

You cannot sensibly initialize a `float` quantity using `cudaMemset`.

Use `cudaMemcpy` instead.

Your `cudaMalloc` operations are also only allocating 1 byte.

Comment: There is also `cuMemset32D` from the driver API which can set the values of all 32 bits of a range of words in global memory

Comment: The exception to what Robert Crovella said is when using `cudaMemset()` to initialize floating-point data to either zero, or NaN: `cudaMemset(ptr, 0xFF, size)` initializes the data to NaN, and `cudaMemset(ptr, 0x00, size)` initializes the data to positive zero.